# SQL Server VM in Azure with In Memory

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, azure-vm, memory-optimized-tables

I am running azure and considering deploying a SQL Server 2014 instance due to the in memory feature, however, I was looking through the documentation and couldn't seem to find how to configure In-Memory, is it enabled by default, what considerations for data do I need to take?

Does any one have any experience with the In memory feature in SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In-Memory is for making your heavily accessed table as memory optimized.
- For a memory optimized table, all data is stored in memory and hence unlike disk based tables, pages don't need to be brought into the buffer pool or cache.
- In order to create a memory optimized table, you need to create a database with a filestream filegroup (along with the use of `CONTAINS MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_DATA`)

  ```
  -- enable for in-memory OLTP - change file path as needed 
  ALTER DATABASE imoltp ADD FILEGROUP imoltp_mod CONTAINS MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_DATA 
  ALTER DATABASE imoltp ADD FILE (name='imoltp_mod1', filename='c:\data\imoltp_mod1') TO FILEGROUP imoltp_mod
  ```

  GO

Now for creating memory optimized tables you have to create table with `WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED=ON)`

[**Getting Started with SQL Server 2014 In-Memory OLTP**](http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2013/06/26/getting-started-with-sql-server-2014-in-memory-oltp.aspx) will give you all the detailed steps to get you started.

For more details, check this BOL article : [In-Memory OLTP (In-Memory Optimization)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133186.aspx)

---

Update:

@cat you have to follow 3 step process

1. [Determining if a Table or Stored Procedure Should Be Ported to In-Memory OLTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn170449.aspx) ,
2. [Determining if a disk based Table or Stored Procedure Should Be Ported to In-Memory OLTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn205133.aspx) -- informs you about which tables in your database will benefit if ported to use In-Memory OLTP and finally
3. After you identify a table that you would like to port to use In-Memory OLTP, you can use the [memory optimization advisor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn284308.aspx) to help you migrate the disk-based database table to In-Memory OLTP.